# Symfony 4 external login check

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I've created a basic login form in Symfony 4 like this, which all works fine:

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        backend_user_provider:
            entity:
                class:
                    App\Entity\User
                    property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        cms:
            switch_user: true
            pattern: ^/
            http_basic: ~
            provider: backend_user_provider
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_submit
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: login
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_BACKEND }
```

Now, what I'd like to achieve is that if a user doesn't exist, I can make a CURL call to a certain external location (with the email and password), and depending on the JSON result (let's say {success:true} or {success:false}) log in the user anyway.

How do I do this? I know about the [Guard component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html), but I can't seem to figure out how to put it in practice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use ChainUserProvider for that purpose and wire it up together with you ExternalUserProvider.

https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/multiple_user_providers.html

Comment: You might want to add a few more details considering that user providers have no access to the password.